Galilei transformation
Assume 2 observers $P$ and $P'$ describe events in time and $3-$dimensional space in spite of mutually paralel and equally oriented axis $x, y, z$ and $x', y', z'$, respectively, where the origin of the system of observer $P'$ in the view of observer $P$ at time $t = t_0$ corresponding to time $t' = 0$ of observer $P'$, has coordinates $(x_0, y_0, z_0)^T$. Let observer $P'$ move in the uniform linear motion given by $\bf{v}$ $= (v_x, v_y, v_z)^T$ in the view of observer $P$.
Find the Galilei transformation giving the link between time-space coordinates of the point events for the two observers:
$t' = t - t_0, x' = x - x_0 - v_xt, y' = y - y_0 - v_yt, z' = z - z_0 - v_zt$.
Solution: It should simply just be $$G =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&0&0&-t_0\\
-v_x&1&0&0&-x_0\\
-v_y & 0 &1 &0 &-y_0\\
-v_z&0&0 &1&-z_0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
but my question is the following: I'm confused by that sentence about origin. Origin of $P'$ in view of $P'$ is always $(0, 0, 0)^T$ and it says that in time $t = t_0$ it is at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)^T$ for $P$. That means $t' = t_0 - t_0 = 0$ (ok), but $0 = x' = x - x_0 - v_xt_0 \implies x = x_0 + v_xt_0 \neq x_0$, which does not seem right. I guess I'm just misinterpreting something, but I guess I need some help.

In my view, the Galilean transformation should be given by
\begin{align}
x^\prime&=x-x_0-v_x(t-t_0);\\
y^\prime&=y-y_0-v_y(t-t_0);\\
z^\prime&=z-z_0-v_z(t-t_0);\\
t^\prime&=t-t_0
\end{align}
Let $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)^T$ be a vector pointing from the origin of $P$ to the event and let $\vec{r}^\prime=(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)^T$ be a vector pointing from the origin of $P^\prime$ to the event. If $\vec{R}$ a vector pointing from the origin of $P$ to the origin of $P^\prime$, then
\begin{align}
\vec{r}^\prime=\vec{r}-\vec{R}. \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{align}
Since

the origin of $P'$ in the view of observer $P$ at time $t = t_0$ corresponding to time $t' = 0$ of observer $P'$, has coordinates $(x_0, y_0, z_0)^T$.

and

$P'$ move in the uniform linear motion given by $\vec{v}= (v_x, v_y, v_z)^T$ in the view of observer $P$.

Then
$$\vec{R}=(x_0, y_0, z_0)^T+\vec{v}(t-t_0)=(x_0+v_x(t-t_0), y_0+v_y(t-t_0), z_0+v_z(t-t_0))^T.$$
Substituting this into $(1)$, we obtain
$$(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)^T=(x,y,z)^T-(x_0+v_x(t-t_0), y_0+v_y(t-t_0), z_0+v_z(t-t_0))^T$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
x^\prime&=x-x_0-v_x(t-t_0);\\
y^\prime&=y-y_0-v_y(t-t_0);\\
z^\prime&=z-z_0-v_z(t-t_0).
\end{align}
Note that, if $t=t_0$ and $\vec{r}^\prime=0$, we have
\begin{align}
x&=x_0;\\
y&=y_0;\\
z&=z_0.
\end{align}

Thanks. With these equations it makes sense. I guess it is just a mistake in the book (in the previous chapters they used just $t' = t$, so they probably forgot to change the rest of the equations to the correct form).
